# How to display a Salesforce CRM Content video in an Apex page?

Tags: video, salesforce, crm

would like to use Salesforce CRM Content Documents to store both video files and also links to external video links (lets say YouTube videos). In fact I already contributed two contents, one is an actual video and the other one is a link to a YouTube video. How can I access and display them in an Apex page?

Comment: Seems that VersionData field of ContentVersion sObject is the way to go:
http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/cookbook/index_Left.htm#CSHID=personal_to_public.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpersonal_to_public.htm|SkinName=webhelp

I should write a client side code (e.g. javascript) to call the webservice and retrieve VersionData; although that's going to be a new challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to call out in this fashion to avoid governor limits

```
[NAME].force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/[CONTENTVERSIONID]
```

There may also be some additional config required to get this working. Please see the following link:

[Make ContentVersion downloadable](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000099sOIAQ)

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing you with part of my code, I hope this helps

1 create in SF `Object` that has `YouTubevideoID`,`ContentDocumentId`,`imgUrl` fields.

2 create class that has

```
public string link {get;set;}
public string tendingAction {get;set;}
public string link {get;set;}
```

3 populate this by this logic

```
public void updateActionAndImege(){
        if(this.YouTubevideoID!=null && this.YouTubevideoID!=''){
            this.tendingAction = 'loadVideo(\''+YouTubevideoID+'\');';
            this.link = 'https://youtube.com/watch?v='+YouTubevideoID;
        }
        if(this.ContentDocumentId!=null && this.ContentDocumentId!=''){
            this.tendingAction = 'OverlayDialogElement.showFilePreview(\'docViewerOverlay\',\'title_'+ContentDocumentId+'\',\'/_swf/121310/sfc\',\''+ContentDocumentId+'\',\'chatter_bubble\',\'false\',\'docViewerContainer\',false,\'docx\',false);';
            this.link = '/'+ContentDocumentId;
        }
        if(this.imgUrl==null || this.imgUrl==''){
            if(this.YouTubevideoID!=null && this.YouTubevideoID!=''){
                this.imgUrl = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+YouTubevideoID+'/hqdefault.jpg';
                isYouTubeImg = true;    
            }
            if(this.ContentDocumentId!=null && this.ContentDocumentId!='')
                this.imgUrl = 'https://c.cs15.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId='+ContentDocumentId+'&operationContext=CHATTER';
        }
```

}

4 show this class on page

```
<img src="{!cl.imgUrl}" alt="Click to preview" class="contentThumbnail {!IF(cl.isYouTubeImg,'yt_thumb_small','')}" title="Click to preview" id="ext-gen4"/>
 <a class="view_m" href="javascript:{!cl.tendingAction}">View </a>
```

6 JS for YouTube Load

```
 function loadVideo(videoID) {
        loadPopup();
        if(ytplayer) {
            ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
        }
        else{
            loadPlayer(videoID);
        }
      }

      // This function is called when an error is thrown by the player
      function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
        alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
      }

      // This function is automatically called by the player once it loads
      function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
        ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
        centerPopup();
        ytplayer.playVideo();
      }

      // The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
      function loadPlayer(videoID) {
        // The video to load
        var videoID = videoID;
        // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        // The element id of the Flash embed
        var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };

        //var pageHeight =  $(window).height();
        var pageWidth =  $(window).width(); var tWidth; var tHeight;
        if(pageWidth <= 760) {tHeight = 278; tWidth = 440;}
        if(pageWidth > 760 && pageWidth <= 980){tHeight = 378; tWidth = 540;}  
        if(pageWidth > 980) {tHeight = 478; tWidth = 640;}
        // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

        swfobject.embedSWF("https://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + 
                           "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                           "videoDiv", tWidth, tHeight, "9", null, null, params, atts);
      }
```

Comment: Shimshon,

Thank you for posting this answer! I think this going to work for YouTube link contents, but I was also looking for a way to render video CRM contents that store an actual video file (not a link to a YouTube video). I think, I should create a page that uses ContentVersion.VersionData to serve the video content and another page that uses jscript (similar to yours) to display the served video.